# Magento. Determine if category is a top level category

Tags: php, magento

I have a collection of categories `$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->getItems();` and then I'm filtering through the results and displaying category thumbnail, name and link on the page.

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $cat): ?>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="<?php echo $cat->getImageUrl() ?>" alt="image">
        <a href="<?php echo $cat->getUrl()?>"><?php echo $cat->getName(); ?></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to do that ONLY for top level categories. So neither root category nor sub-categories should be included into the results set.

if I use `magento`'s helper method to get top level categories then it doesn't provide me an access to all that methods like `getImageUrl` and `getUrl` that I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add    filter by level by 2

```
    Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('level', 2);
```

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem indeed but isn't it not flexible?